# Is it possible to calculate inverse sine without using pi?

Tags: trigonometry, pi

I'm asking this in a programming context (because I'm a programmer) but I'm looking for general answers as well.

In programming, all of the implementations of `asin` ($\arcsin$) that I have seen involve, at some point, the use of a constant directly derived from $\pi$ (for example, [this implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-2026/Source/Intel/asin.c) uses a hard-coded $\pi/2$).

My question is: Is there another method of calculating $\arcsin$ that doesn't rely on knowing $\pi$?

The only method I have been able to imagine is to substitute calculated approximations of $\pi$ in place for the hard-coded values in the implementations (e.g. approximate the area of a circle by counting discrete pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2<r^2$ and dividing by $r^2$, or using a Taylor series approximation). This is not really in the "spirit" of what I'm looking for. I am more wondering if a method exists that doesn't involve calculating an approximation of $\pi$ to directly substitute in place of a constant.

Comment: To clarify: The CodeGolf link was included to illustrate my original motivation for asking; but the intention of my question is to calculate $\arcsin$, not to calculate $\pi$ itself. I am moving that paragraph into the comments here to avoid confusion:

Comment: My motivation for asking has to do with (a rather poor, in my opinion) recent challenge posted on [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/pi-calculation-code-golf/), which presents the challenge of calculating $\pi$ itself -- but most of the answers indirectly involve $\pi$ at some point (e.g. $\arccos(-1)$). Dissatisfaction with the answers led me on an unsuccessful search for implementations of trigonometric functions that do not involve a hard-coded value directly derived from $\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use power series to compute
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^{-1}(x)
&=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac t2\right)^{2k}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac x2\right)^{2k+1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
$(2)$ follows from the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem).

To get better convergence near $x=1$, we can use
$$
\sin^{-1}(x)=3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\tag{4}
$$
Of course, you might consider this cheating since $3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)=\pi/2$.

Comment: Isn't approximation of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ near $1$ another problem though?

Comment: @ChristophPegel: There are many algorithms to compute square root. For example, we could iterate $$u_{n+1}=\frac12\left(u_n+\frac{1-x^2}{u_n}\right)$$ which converges quickly to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Taylor series $x+x^3/6+(3 x^5)/40+(5 x^7)/112+(35 x^9)/1152+(63 x^{11})/2816+O(x^{12})$, which doesn't use $\pi$.  To improve accuracy, you can use the half-angle formula to reduce the argument.  You can test against a hard-coded $\frac 12$ or something convenient to know when you can stop.